# my tire is wobbling and I need to know possibilities!

Tags: tires

I had a flat tire on my front right and I definitely need an alignment because they were wearing on the inside of both front tires. I moved my rear tires to the front and just replaced and balanced the two in the back. Ever since my front ride tire wobbles (at any speed) if it hits any groove or anything. I wanted to hold off the alignment for a little longer because I'm super broke now, but also scared it might be something worse or more expensive. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the wheel seated properly? Are the nuts done up tightly? Try taking it off and putting it back on...

Answer (score 2):

Safely jack one or both front wheels off the ground. Manually spin the tire while watching the tread pattern. If you notice a shift in the tread you have a bad tire. Sometimes the belts the tires are made of shift under the tread. It is also referred to as tread squirm or shift. It can be subtle enough to not be noticeable on the rear but can be felt when the tires are mounted on the front.